# I am trying to get json data from bitbns.com but getting an error

Tags: javascript, json

I am very new to javascript and I am trying to get json data from bitbns but getting error 
  - "(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://www.bitbns.com’)."

I searched a lot on internet but could not find any solution.

```
<script>

url="https://www.bitbns.com/order/getTicker";
var request = new Request(url);

fetch(request, {mode: "cors",
}).then(function(response) {
       return response.json();
    }).then(function(j) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(j)); 
    }).catch(function(error) {  
        console.log('Request failed', error)  
    });
console.log(request.headers)
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this at all?

Comment: Their API seems not to support CORS. You need to get it via your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
var url="https://www.bitbns.com/order/getTicker";
let x = proxyUrl + url
fetch(x, {mode: "cors",
}).then(function(response) {
       return response.json();
    }).then(function(j) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(j)); 
    }).catch(function(error) {  
        console.log('Request failed', error)  
    });
```

This will get things rolling, but it is better not to use this for production due to lack of security.

**https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/** is a link that add cors header.

Comment: mark as answer by clicking on the tick so others can use as well

Comment: Thanks. You taught me one more thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found on https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299915-How-to-make-an-ajax-request-cross-origin-CORS

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http:ww.abc.com?callback=?',
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function () { },
            failure: function () { },
            complete: function (data) {
                if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {
                    errorLog.push({ IP: Host, Status: 'SUCCESS' })
                }
                else {
                    errorLog.push({ IP: Host, Status: 'FAIL' })
                }
            }
        });
```